# Does using setters still break one way data flow principle?

Tags: vue.js

I'm building a data table component that nests subcomponents about five levels deep. e.g. (simplified) `controller`, `table`, `thead`/ `tbody`, `tr`, `td`.

The top component (`controller`) contains all the definitions and passes them down.

However, the last component in the chain (`td`) is performing some calculations on the data and those calculations are then passed to **other** subcomponents in the render stack.

I really hate to break the one-way data flow principle here, but we're talking tens of thousands of calculations, and hundreds of events bubbling up four levels. Bubbling up manually, of course.

I can do it using event bus pattern or a shared state pattern and I think that would comply with all the recommended practices.

However, I have found that simply declaring a setter on the affected prop attributes and placing deep watches on the props involved (in the few strategic places) results in much faster code.

What is the recommended way of solving a data-flow problem like this?

**Edit: asked to provide an example. Hopefully this oversimplification will do:**

controller is responsible for declaring table columns. It also contains a property called maxWidth containing the measured maximum td width for the column.

As a consequence components `table`, `thead`/ `tbody`, and `tr` all contain prop called `columns` while `td` contains `column` as in one column from the `columns` array.

Say `td` measures rendered width and reports that back to the controller so that it can decide which columns to hide.

- **Approach 1: (props down, events up)**

  `td` emits event, `tr` captures it and re-emits, etc. until it is captured by `controller` which then performs the necessary calculations and thus modifies the `columns`, triggering a re-render of the entire stack.
- **Approach 2: (vuex)**

  The columns array is in storage with action defined for adjusting column measurements?
- **Approach 3: (property setter)**

  The columns array declares a setter / method for adjusting maxWidth value.

  Note how a method would essentially be the same as in vuex approach while a setter makes the assignment syntax somewhat less obvious that we're using an actual method for changing the state.

Also note how I myself fail to see the difference between vuex approach, column setter method or column property setter... Hence the question.

Edit 2: more clarification

If I'm using a setter, linter will immediately complain about `vue/no-mutating-props` whereas it won't do so when I'm using a method with basically the same code, except that it isn't a property setter, but a "separate" method.

Would that automatically mean that using a method is OK as it's semantically distinct from assigning a value?

Comment: 1. It's ok 2. It's ok but may be cumbersome to handle multiple instances in store, they need to be distinguished somehow 3. It has the downsides that you listed. 1 and 3 can be made easier with provide/inject for event bus or reactive object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference: I have forgone setters since they seemed too obvious and linter complained about property modification.

Instead I have created setter functions, e.g. `setMaximumWidth` on the object containing the property.

This solution ***seems*** like it conforms to best practices, at least as far as I understand them, and doesn't really change the approach.

I'm happy, but will probably get bashed some time for not using something more obvious, whatever that may be.